# Loop Until Condition Is Met

Tags: loops, parameters

I am extremely new to coding so please bear with me.

I am trying to create a loop until a condition is met, namely, an email address. This is what I have so far:

```
first = input("Please enter your first name: ")
surname = input("Please enter your surname: ")
email = input("Please enter your email address: ")
emailconfirm = input("Please confirm email address: ")
if email != emailconfirm:
    input ("Emails are different. Please kindly confirm email address: ")
cell = input("Please enter cell number: ")
```

How do I code to enter a cell/ mobile number without it printing until the emailconfirm == email condition  is  met?

I know this may be simple to many but it is VERY early days for me. Many thanks for the assistance.

Graeme

Tried tutorials but I just cannot get it right :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a while loop and update the value of `emailconfirm` in each iteration

```
email = input("Please enter your email address: ")
emailconfirm = input("Please confirm email address: ")
while email != emailconfirm:
    emailconfirm = input("Emails are different. Please kindly confirm email address: ")
```

Comment: That's rather embarrassing. :) Thank you SO much. Makes me realise how far I have to go.